# Use of subjunctive in translation of movie quote

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, conjunctive

I want to translate the phrase

> rise and rise again until lambs become lions

into Llatin, with the idea of never giving up or daring to the impossible. My translation so far is

> surge et surge ad agni fiant leones

but I'm not sure whether the use of *ad* is correct or whether the verb should be subjunctive. Please correct me if you can.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what movie is this from?

Comment: Robin Hood (2010) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use *ad* in this way, because *ad* is a preposition with the accusative. Even if you could, it would still not help you, because *ad* simply doesn't mean “until.”

For “until,” the usual Latin equivalents are *dum*, *donec* and *quoad*. They all have the somewhat irritating property that they can also mean “so long as” or “while.” The famous *Dum spiro, spero* obviously does not mean “I hope until I breathe” – but you have to interpret that from context.

In the “while” meaning, the indicative is used. (Or at least that is what is taught as good classical prose composition – the real picture is somewhat more complicated.)

But in the “until” meaning, both the indicative and the subjunctive are found. If you peruse Latin grammar books, you'll find a certain variety of attempts to systematize, explain and express the reasons for using either one; but in general, the gist is that the subjunctive expresses some *desired* outcome that the subject of the main clause wants to bring about or await. It is frequently used with verbs of waiting, remaining, holding back, etc. to give something else time to happen. The indicative, on the other hand, is used when the speaker does not want to express such an intent, either because it does not exist or he does not want to emphasize it.

A good example for the indicative would be (Sueton, [*Divus Iulius* 82](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/suetonius/suet.caesar.html#82)):

> [Caesar] exanimis […] aliquamdiu iacuit, **donec** […] tres servoli domum **rettulerunt.**
> *Caesar lay dead for a while, until he was carried back home by three slaves.*

A good example for the subjunctive would be (Cicero, [*Tusc.* 4, 36](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/tusc4.shtml#78)):

> His [iratis] subtrahendi sunt ei, in quos impetum conantur facere, **dum** se ipsi **colligant.**
> *Angry people must be denied access to those they try to attack until they have collected themselves.*

(Note: Cicero and Caesar never used *donec* in the subjunctive, so some grammarians do not consider it allowable in exemplary prose.)

Now in your example (perhaps somewhat counterintuitively?) I would say that the change from lambs to lions is *not* stated as the desired outcome of prolonged rising, simply because it is an exhortation. The speaker wants to say that this will be the sure outcome – and therefore the present indicative or the future exactum would be appropriate:

> Surge atque iterum surge, dum agni leones facti erunt.

Note that you could also say *eritis* – since presumably the speaker is talking to the “lambs.”